# How to make https available for the clients in a linux server

Tags: linux, ssl, https, openssl

I have a oracle linux server and i am able to access the https of my local web directory WITHIN the linux server. But if i am trying to access it from the outside client PC https does not works.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the error that your are seeing? It should help answer this question

Answer (score 1):

If you can access it going to https://localhost and the browser doesn't give you an error that tells me the server is set up correctly and your certificate is valid.

There are several reasons why you wouldn't be able to access it externally. Are there iptables rules allowing inbound traffic over 443? Do external clients have a route to your server? Is there a firewall in the path, and is it allowing traffic over 443 to your oracle server?

How do you define not working? Are you getting connection refused? Is it timing out?

Comment: Hi, i have allowed both input and output for port 443 in my iptables also external clients can connect to my HTTP url so that means if i have not mistaken the routing has done properly. Also there is no specific routers used for this. Im getting the error message, "Secure Connection Failed" in firefox.

Comment: Can you telnet to port 443 on your server from an external client? If a connection is established, then there are no network connectivity problems, and you need to start looking at application-layer issues. Firefox doesnt support connections over sslv3 anymore, so make sure you are using TLS1 or higher. Are your certificates self-signed? Maybe firefox doesn't trust whoever issued them.

Comment: Hi iam able to telnet to the other ports except 443. What should i do now?

Comment: Are you getting connection refused or does it just hang? You are probably getting connection refused, which means there is something in the path blocking traffic over 443. Without examining your environment it is hard to say, but you might want to double check your iptables rules - as you said there were no routers (and I am assuming hardware firewalls) in the path. Feel free to paste them here and I can take a look.

Comment: Connecting To 192.168.*.*...Could not open connection to the host, on port 443:
 Connect failed
this is what im getting if im telnet this. But i tried to turn off the iptables and then i tried still it was the same so i assume that, there is nothing wrong with the iptables setup. Appreciate your support. Thank you.

Comment: Make double sure 443 is open an listening on the server by running `netstat -at`

It sounds like there is a device in the path that isn't allowing traffic over 443. Traceroute from the client to the server and see which hops it takes. Every hop should be checked, but particularly routers and firewalls. Refused means somewhere in the path the connection is actively being shut down.

Comment: hi i finally got it working the problem was with my browsers when i try to access https from an old browser version its working it seems like i have to update my SSL certificate. Thanks.